# Not sure if my manage.py script is working

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS and Python. I am trying to run  `python manage.py runserver 0:8080 .` This has code to write to dynamodb.

The cli is stuck at below :

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 07, 2020 - 16:54:55
Django version 1.11.27, using settings 'docproc.settings'
Starting development server at http://0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Not sure how to proceed. Can someone please help?

Comment: This looks like expected behavior -- it looks like you are starting a Django development web server process, and it's starting up successfully, listening, waiting for incoming HTTP requests.  If that isn't what you expected, you may need to edit the question to explain in more detail why you are expecting a different result.  If you are following a tutorial, then providing a link to that document would probably prove useful.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am trying to send SNS notification to the EC2 instance. Can you let me know how where do I see the incoming HTTP requests and subscription urls ?
I have port 80 and 22 opened as inbound in the security group. But I am not able to find the subscription url when I run manage.py.